# How to reindex object to text?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I reindex an object type field like:

```json
{
  "Foo": {
    "properties": {
      "ID": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "Name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to its text representation:

```json
{
  "Foo": {
    "type": "text",
    "index": "false"
  }
}
```

With raw reindex I'm getting an error: `Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:141`

Comment: Pls give complete commands & steps you are doing in detail - that would help others

Comment: You cannot index an object as a text. You'll need to change the way your source looks like either at your client or using ingestion pipelines to do that.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas is ingest the only way? No chance with reindex API scripts?

Comment: You might achieve that with Reindex scripts as well. Point is that you need to convert your structure to a string. Do you mind explaining your use case? This doesn't look practical.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found only this questions, so here's my solution after some digging.

The data in your source is not a string, so Elasticsearch will not be able to find the content. You will need to flatten the contents and replace the 'Foo' field with its flattened value.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "target_index"
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """
      if (ctx._source.Foo != null {
        String flatText = '[';
        for (def item : ctx._source.Foo) {
          List keys = new ArrayList(item.keySet());
          Collections.sort(keys);
          flatText += '{';
          for (def key : keys) {
            flatText += key + ':' + item[key] + ',';
          }
          flatText = flatText.substring(0, flatText.length() - 1); // Remove last comma
          flatText += '},';
        }
        flatText = flatText.substring(0, flatText.length() - 1); // Remove last comma
        flatText += ']';
        ctx._source.Foo = flatText;
      }
    """
  }
}
```

Notice that you have to check for `ctx._source.Foo != null` or the script will fail.
If 'Foo' is inside another field, you need to check for the whole hierarchy, like
`(ctx._source.Higher != null && ctx._source.Higher.Foo != null)`